# Why Features.xml changes not showing custom feature switch screen?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am adding custom feature in "Custom Feature Switch" screen, I am following all guild lines but my custom columns are not showing, I have added  Features.xml xml file with proper extension(namespace) class and add columns in database and build the project, but checkbox is not showing in CS20100000 screen.
I have level 2 developer rights, where may i do mistake?
FeatureSet extension class added properly and xml also added, anything i am missing?

In debugging "CS20100000.cs" file, I have found 
`var featureAttributes = cache.GetAttributes(null, field).OfType<FeatureAttribute>`();

giving 0 featureAttributes, that's-why it is not visible while i have added Features.xml file with proper tag as suggested in document, any thing else am i missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Feature.xml changes are not showing in Enable/Disable custom feature UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212354/feature-xml-changes-are-not-showing-in-enable-disable-custom-feature-ui)

Comment: No, still issue, i can see checkbox after adding attribute but check/uncheck doesn't apply permission. I don't know why XML is loading. I have added a comment in above link. May you suggest anything more.?