# Feature.xml changes are not showing in Enable/Disable custom feature UI?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Add custom feature checkbox is not showing in custom feature UI, My finding

```
var featureAttributes = cache.GetAttributes(null, field).OfType<FeatureAttribute>();
```

giving 0 featureAttributes, that's-why it is not visible while i have added Features.xml file with proper tag as suggested in documentation, any thing else am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Feature.XML should be in root of our Project.
2. Attribute
       [Feature(false, DisplayName = "MY NEW FEATURE")], should always be
       there.
3. If want to see "MY NEW FEATURE" under a root then look at
       below code.

   ## region UsrMyNewFeature

   public abstract class usrMyNewModuleFeature : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field { }

   [Feature(false, DisplayName = "MY Module FEATURE")]
   public bool? UsrMyNewModuleFeature { get; set; }

   ## endregion

   ## region UsrMyNewFeature

   public abstract class usrMyNewFeature : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field { }

   [Feature(false, typeof(usrMyNewModuleFeature), DisplayName = "MY NEW FEATURE")]
   public bool? UsrMyNewFeature { get; set; }

   ## endregion

Comment: Hi Brenden, Everything work fine in my development environment, But i am getting issue, when same code give to other development environment then checkboxes are not showing in Enable/Disable Feature screen, am i doing any setting mistake in his database?

Comment: HI, I have parent/child relationship betwwen checkbox, when i check/uncheck checkbox then child enable/disabled, but checkboxes are not check/uncheck, what should i do to check/uncheck on parent?

Answer (score 1):

All you should need is the table extension for the FeatureSet table. Here is an example:

```
public sealed class FeaturesSetExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CS.FeaturesSet>
{
    #region UsrMyNewFeature
    public abstract class usrMyNewFeature : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrMyNewFeature> { }

    [Feature(false, DisplayName = "MY NEW FEATURE")]
    public bool? UsrMyNewFeature { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

I end up with the following:

[image]

You will create a Feature.xml file to then limit pages related to the new feature switch.

If you need to access the switch (which might not register until added into the features.xml):

```
PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSetExtension.usrMyNewFeature>()
```

Comment: After adding attribute "Feature(false, DisplayName = "MY NEW FEATURE")]", i can see checkbox, But documentation never suggested to add this, why? feature.xml is not working ,I checkbox checked/unchecked, but permission not apply, anything wrong here? what do you mean why limit pages? I have exclude my feature.xml file and checkbox still show, why? How may i add parent child checkbox relation, like Parent then under of that multiple checkbox?

Comment: May you provide me detail document to add custom feature in FeatureSet? Basically my point is, why access permissions are not working evan i check/uncheck checkbox, where am i doing mistake?

Comment: https://www.acumatica.com/media/2020/02/AcumaticaERP_CustomizationGuide.pdf

Comment: How to check/uncheck child(feature) checkbox when parent feature check/uncheck?

Comment: You need to include the parent in your child FeatureAttribute. Ex: [Feature(typeof(FeaturesSet.myParentFeature), DisplayName = "My Child Feature")]

Comment: Thanks @Brendon sir, I already did as you suggested , I think this is the issue with custom Feature, Already reported to Acumatica team.

Comment: In our case we have added a few custom child features to an existing parent feature without issue. Not sure if the main parent feature is custom (sounds like your case)

Comment: I am not using existing Parent feature, I have my own Parent.